# Foreign key not updating in entity frame work

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have a class like

```
 public class Document
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public User ModifiedBy { get; set; } 
            public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; } 

        }
```

Here  “User”  is a class with some properties (all are primitive types )
Here is my mapping of class Document

`HasRequired(a => a.ModifiedBy).WithMany().Map(b => b.MapKey("ModifiedBy")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false)`;

So in table "Document" ModifiedBy is a foreign key.

I am trying to update the ModifiedBy field of a document having id 10

```
Document  document=  new Document();
using (DBContext ctx = new DBContex())   {

    User loggedinUser =ctx.Users.Where(u=>u.LoginId==loggedInUserId).FirstOrDefault() as User;

    document.id=10;
    document.ModifiedBy = loggedinUser;
    document.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
    ctx.Entry(document).State = EntityState.Modified;
    ctx.SaveChanges();   
}
```

But the ModifiedBy  field is not updating. only ModifiedDate field is updating.

Note that I don't what to update User table.
I just want to update Document table

Comment: You want to get document from the database by that particular ID. `ctx.Users.Where(u=>u.LoginId==loggedInUserId).FirstOrDefault() as User` can be reduced to `ctx.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.LoginId == loggedInUserId)` and also you need to think whether to use `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault`.

Comment: Thanks but that is not an answer

Comment: That is why it is in the comments..... and p.s. it also is an answer, the top line is, just not extremely explicit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on [Entity Framework does not update Foreign Key object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571931/entity-framework-does-not-update-foreign-key-object)
I created

```
public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

[DataMember]
[ForeignKey("ModifiedBy")] 
public User ModifiedUser
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

That means I additionally introduced a primitive type(string ModifiedBy ) for Modified User and specified ForeignKey.
That resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do in your situation:

```
using (var ctx = new DBContext())   {

    var loggedinUser = ctx.Users.SingleOrDefault(u=>u.LoginId==loggedInUserId);

    if (loggedinUser == null) throw new Exception("Can't find logged in user");

    var document = ctx.Documents.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == 10);

    if (document == null) throw new Exception("Can't find associated document");

    document.ModifiedBy = loggedinUser;
    document.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

    ctx.SaveChanges();   
}
```

Now the reason I do this.

When I do `var document = ctx.Documents.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == 10);` I'm calling that particular entity into EF's change tracker. Which means if I change any of its properties such as `ModifiedDate` EF will automatically do `ctx.Entry(document).State = EntityState.Modified;`.

If you don't do this, and you want to carry on the way you do it, then you need to add this line (I believe):

```
document.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
ctx.Documents.Attach(document); 
ctx.Entry(document).State = EntityState.Modified;
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This a sample only I don't have just 2 properties.I have around 15 properties. So doing an update as you do wont be good for me

Comment: Well, I have answered your question above. The case that you have presented in your comments isn't really a Stackoverflow question. It is more for Meta Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks  Callum,But ctx.Documents.Attach(document); 
ctx.Entry(document).State = EntityState.Modified; not helping me